# dd: error writing an image. No space left on device

Tags: partition, hard-disk, disk-image

I am trying to create an image of an embedded system running Debian 32bit. I ran Rescuezilla which is live Ubuntu USB. sda is the disk where the OS is installed.

`lsblk` listed sda as 7.5G
My destination is an NTFS formatted drive which according to `lsblk` is also 7.5G

After mounting the destination drive, I used `dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/newimage.img bs=1M status=progress`

After 10 mins, I got an error:

```
dd: error writing '/mnt/newimage.img':No space left on device
7588+0 records in
7587+0 records out
7956467712 bytes (8.0 GB, 7.4GiB) copied, 1440.18 s, 5.5MB/s
```

Is the source larger than destination here?

Comment: Hi I would check the real size instead of the one provided by lsblk which is rounded. can you provide df -T which will speak in 1K instead of G. It seems you are lacking 1M on the output (7588 vs 7587).

Comment: Note that your `dd` output already shows 8 GB copied.

Comment: Output of `lsblk -b` on the ubuntu live cd shows that:
sda size is 8012390400
sdb size is the same 8012390400. However, the NTFS partition of sdb1 8010072064. I mounted the sdb1 partition to /mnt and tried to copy the entire sda which is bigger than sdb1. Perhaps that's the cause of the error?

df -T of mounted sdb1 is 7822332 (1K-blocks)

Comment: @terdon - then why the error ?